# Unable to load backend servers URL via haproxy

Tags: load-balancing, redhat, haproxy

when we hit https://abc.domain.com/global its able to reach the backend server but the page keeps on loading. direct links to backend servers work and able to telnet to the servers as well. for ex https://srv1:8180/D2 and https://srv2:8180/D2 works

Could anyone please suggest what is missing? this is my first handson on haproxy. Selinux is disabled. haproxy server on redhat 7.9 and haproxy version 1.7.1

Below is the configuration file

```
   defaults
    mode                    http  
    log                     global  
    option                  httplog  
    #option                  dontlognull  
    option http-server-close
    option forwardfor       except 127.0.0.0/8
    option                  redispatch
    retries                 3
    timeout http-request    10s
    timeout queue           1m
    timeout connect         10s
    timeout client          1m
    timeout server          10m
    timeout http-keep-alive 10s
    timeout check           10s
    maxconn                 3000

    stats enable
    stats uri /stats
    stats realm Haproxy\ Statistics
    stats auth *:*

frontend https-in  
         mode http  
         bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/pki/tls/private/haproxy.pem  
         #        redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }  
         acl test_host hdr(host) -i abc.domain.com  
         acl d2nsh     path_beg -i /global  
         use_backend testd2nsh if test_host d2nsh  

frontend http-in
         bind *:80
         mode http
         option httplog
         ##
         acl test_host hdr(host) -i abc.domain.com   
         ##
         acl d2nsh     path_beg -i /global  
         ##
    
##
backend testd2nsh
        mode http
        balance roundrobin
        option httpclose
        option forwardfor
        cookie JSESSIONID prefix nocache

        reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /global/(.*) \1\ /D2/\2
        server srv1_8180 srv1:8180 ssl verify none check cookie s1
        server srv1_8190 srv1:8190 ssl verify none check cookie s2
        server srv2_8180 srv2:8180 ssl verify none check cookie s3
        server srv2_8190 srv2:8190 ssl verify none check cookie s4

  
##
```

Answer (score 0):

Which version of HAProxy do your use?
`haproxy -vv`

Just a wild guess but on the srv*:8180 does not exist the `/global` URL and your get a redirect to `https://srv*:8180/D2`

If this is the case then try to set the path in the backend.
[http-request set-path](http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/2.5/configuration.html#4.2-http-request%20set-path)

```
backend testd2nsh
  # other configs

  http-request set-path /D2

  # rest of the config
```

Some of servers and applications can be configured to know that they run behind a reverse Proxy and adopt the redirects like the tomcat

Comment: Version  
    HA-Proxy version 1.7.1 2016/12/13  

    Requirement  
    URL  
    https://abc.domain.com/global  

    Targets  
    https://srv1:8180/D2  
    https://srv2:8180/D2  

    logs  
    https-in~ testd2nsh/frncetd2s01_8190 0/0/2/169/172 200 7705 - - --NR 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 
    "GET /global/ HTTP/1.1"  
    [05/Jan/2022:12:28:35.649] https-in~ testd2nsh/srv1_8180 0/0/2/5/7 304 195 - - --NN 
    0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "GET /global/x3_portal/x3_portal.nocache.js HTTP/1.1"  
    https-in~ testd2nsh/srv2_8180 0/0/2/21/23 200 506 - - --NR 0/0/0/0/0 0/0 "POST

Comment: @Aleksander  
redirection works with this rule
reqrep ^([^\ :]*)\ /global/(.*) \1\ /D2/\2  

However backened server app page keep on loading but never loads.